# Workaround for Twitter Bootstrap modal fade issue in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, twitter-bootstrap

I found a few topics started on this issue however none about any workarounds for MVC environments. For everyone not familiar with the topic. Modals in twitter bootstrap 3.1.1 look faded, similar to the background. [Check it here](http://storage5.static.itmages.com/i/14/0218/h_1392741693_9077886_bbf7fe9fed.png)

What would be the workaround for this problem in Code Igniter or any other MVC?

The code that I use:

```
    <!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Twitter bootstrap or any other CSS frameworks and The PHP frameworks such as CodeIgniter have no intersect. What do you mean by "workaround"?

Comment: Some solutions say that you should put the modal right after the <body> which wouldn't be correct when you use VIEWS.

Comment: You could use the modals everywhere inside the body. I've done several projects using these frameworks and I've never faced any problem with integrating them. If you have any trouble, update the question with the code you've tried so far.